# How to reduce the font size in jQuery UI tab panel header?

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

I'm using the [jQuery UI tabs](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/) but am not sure how to reduce the font size to, say, 75% of what it is currently?

```
        Nunc tincidunt
        Proin dolor
        Aenean lacinia
```

In other words, in the example below, I want the three header labels above to be about 75% of their current size:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
    });
    </script>



<div class="demo">

<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1">Nunc tincidunt</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-2">Proin dolor</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-3">Aenean lacinia</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tabs-1">
        <p>Proin elit arcu, rutrum commodo, vehicula tempus, commodo a, risus. Curabitur nec arcu. Donec sollicitudin mi sit amet mauris. Nam elementum quam ullamcorper ante. Etiam aliquet massa et lorem. Mauris dapibus lacus auctor risus. Aenean tempor ullamcorper leo. Vivamus sed magna quis ligula eleifend adipiscing. Duis orci. Aliquam sodales tortor vitae ipsum. Aliquam nulla. Duis aliquam molestie erat. Ut et mauris vel pede varius sollicitudin. Sed ut dolor nec orci tincidunt interdum. Phasellus ipsum. Nunc tristique tempus lectus.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-2">
        <p>Morbi tincidunt, dui sit amet facilisis feugiat, odio metus gravida ante, ut pharetra massa metus id nunc. Duis scelerisque molestie turpis. Sed fringilla, massa eget luctus malesuada, metus eros molestie lectus, ut tempus eros massa ut dolor. Aenean aliquet fringilla sem. Suspendisse sed ligula in ligula suscipit aliquam. Praesent in eros vestibulum mi adipiscing adipiscing. Morbi facilisis. Curabitur ornare consequat nunc. Aenean vel metus. Ut posuere viverra nulla. Aliquam erat volutpat. Pellentesque convallis. Maecenas feugiat, tellus pellentesque pretium posuere, felis lorem euismod felis, eu ornare leo nisi vel felis. Mauris consectetur tortor et purus.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-3">
        <p>Mauris eleifend est et turpis. Duis id erat. Suspendisse potenti. Aliquam vulputate, pede vel vehicula accumsan, mi neque rutrum erat, eu congue orci lorem eget lorem. Vestibulum non ante. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Fusce sodales. Quisque eu urna vel enim commodo pellentesque. Praesent eu risus hendrerit ligula tempus pretium. Curabitur lorem enim, pretium nec, feugiat nec, luctus a, lacus.</p>
        <p>Duis cursus. Maecenas ligula eros, blandit nec, pharetra at, semper at, magna. Nullam ac lacus. Nulla facilisi. Praesent viverra justo vitae neque. Praesent blandit adipiscing velit. Suspendisse potenti. Donec mattis, pede vel pharetra blandit, magna ligula faucibus eros, id euismod lacus dolor eget odio. Nam scelerisque. Donec non libero sed nulla mattis commodo. Ut sagittis. Donec nisi lectus, feugiat porttitor, tempor ac, tempor vitae, pede. Aenean vehicula velit eu tellus interdum rutrum. Maecenas commodo. Pellentesque nec elit. Fusce in lacus. Vivamus a libero vitae lectus hendrerit hendrerit.</p>
    </div>
</div>

</div><!-- End demo -->
```

Answer (score 2):

A good solution would be to add a class to the a tag, and target this in CSS.

For example :

```
 <li><a class="font75 " href="#tabs-1">Nunc tincidunt</a></li>
 <li><a class="font75 " href="#tabs-2">Proin dolor</a></li>
 <li><a class="font75 " href="#tabs-3">Aenean lacinia</a></li>
```

CSS would then be :

```
.font75 {font-size:75%}
```

Make sure that the class you add to the tabs is not a reserved class in the UI plug in.

Comment: Probably you'll have to add `!important` modifier after style declaration because jQuery-UI assigns font-size dynamically and overrides it.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the jQuery UI css files as well - if so you can customise these quite easily - http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/